# How do I theme the "The website encountered an unexpected error" page?

Tags: 7, theming

How do I set the theme to use for the error page showing an unhandled exception like the one shown in this screenshot?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors in Drupal 7 handled by [`includes/errors.inc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21errors.inc/7.x) file, and the **The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.** error use the *maintenance_page* theme see from *includes/errors.inc*

```
print theme('maintenance_page', array(
        'content' => t('The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.'),
      ));
      exit;
```

So if you want to theme the error page, you theme the `maintenance_page` to do so take a look at [Theming the Drupal maintenance page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/tools-and-best-practices/theming-the-drupal-maintenance-page).